# JavaScript: Last Modified Date From 24 Hours to 12 Hours

Tags: javascript

Dear JavaScript Experts:

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the hour format in the last modified date JavaScript code. This is the code that I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("This page was last modified on: " + document.lastModified +"");
</script>
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. I am extremely new to JavaScript and Stack Overflow so I'm excited about asking my first question.

Thanks,

Michael K.

Comment: To be clear: You want the last date that **your javascript CODE was modified** or **your web site**?

Comment: I would like to have the date and time that my website was last updated. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You could create a Date object out of it and then display that in the format you want. `var myDate = new Date(document.lastModified)`

Comment: Where **document.lastModified** comes from??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of doing it manually : http://jsfiddle.net/ex9T7/

```
alert(formatDate(document.lastModified))


function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date);
    var hh = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    var dd = "AM";
    var h = hh;
    if (h >= 12) {
        h = hh-12;
        dd = "PM";
    }
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    }
    m = m<10?"0"+m:m;

    s = s<10?"0"+s:s;

    /* if you want 2 digit hours:
    h = h<10?"0"+h:h; */

    var pattern = new RegExp("0?"+hh+":"+m+":"+s);

    var replacement = h+":"+m;
    /* if you want to add seconds
    replacement += ":"+s;  */
    replacement += " "+dd;    

    return date.replace(pattern,replacement);
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me... I did have to add the following to have it display on the page: `document.write(formatDate("This page was last modified on: " + document.lastModified +""))`. Now I would like to know how to get it in the right time zone. Right now it says it was last modified on: 06/07/2014 1:59 PM, when it is actually: 06/07/2014 7:08 AM where I am.